# KnokBack of Player

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d

I want a knock Back effect with this code but I dont know how.
I am new to coding still learning stuff !

This is my code where i want the KnockBack to have effect.
PlayerMovement.MyBody is a script with the rigidbody attached.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// If We CanDamage LifeScorecount minus 1 and stes CanDamage to false and starts Coroutine. 
    /// If Life is higher than 0 change thet text to the new life
    /// If life is 0 then stop Time and start Coroutine RestartGame
    /// </summary>
    public void DealDamage()
    {
        if(CanDamage)
        {
            Anim.Play("Stun");
            LifeScoreCount--;
            Vector2 direction = (transform.position, 0);

            PlayerMovement.myBody.AddForce(direction * -10f);

            if (LifeScoreCount >= 0)
            {
                TextLife.text = "x" + LifeScoreCount;
            }
            if (LifeScoreCount == 0)
            {
                Time.timeScale = 0f;
                StartCoroutine(RestartGame());
            }
            CanDamage = false;
            StartCoroutine(WaitForDamage());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you share the PlayerMovement code?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you implemented your Movement and how you want your knock back to look like.
Assuming you simply want to push the rigidbody away, you can add a force like you already tried. To use a "one-time" push, you can use ForceMode.Impulse.
For the direction you want to use two points. The transform.position of the object, getting pushed away, subtracted by the transform.position of the object, which is pushing the character away.
So if you want an enemy to push away the player, you could try something like this:

```
Vector3 playerPosition = new Vector3(transform.position.x, 0, transform.position.z);
Vector3 enemyPosition = new Vector3(enemy.transform.position.x, 0, enemy.transform.position.z);
Vector3 knockbackDirection = (playerPosition - enemyPosition).normalized;
float power = 2f
rb.AddForce(knockbackDirection * power, ForceMode.Impulse);
```

If you also want the knockback to work along the y-axis, just use the Transform positions instead of the new Vector3.
If you don't have the reference to the enemy, you maybe want to add a parameter, so whenever an enemy damages the player, he will pass his own position as a parameter.

And maybe consider using a [SerializeField](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SerializeField.html) for the knockback force, so you can easily edit it in the editor.